# IPython Notebook image loading syntax

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda

I'm taking this [Coursera course on linear algebra](https://www.coursera.org/course/matrix), which is Python based. I got so far as to produce some initial plots and work with complex numbers on IP Notebook. I am using Windows, and the display of the Notebook is on Chrome.

I got to a command to call a jpeg image on the plot and the line written by the instructor is:

`from image import *`

I am getting the following error message:

```
    In [7]:  from image import *
             File "image.py", line 98
             print("Hit Enter once the image is displayed.... ", end="")
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I believe that the call may be pointing to the `image.py` downloaded from [this site](http://resources.codingthematrix.com).

Comment: I guess this should be asked in the forum of that course. Which version of Python are you running ? And in the course?

Comment: OK. The course hasn't really started, yet, although the material is available, and I'm familiarizing with the software issues that I'll encounter down the road.

Comment: what's the output for `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: `2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (32-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 14:13:17) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]` Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll go and assume that in the course they're working with python 3, so the error you're getting is because of the print function.

```
from image import *
    File "image.py", line 98
    print("Hit Enter once the image is displayed.... ", end="")
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Either use Python 3, or `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: Thank you. I went ahead and ran `from __future__ import print_function`. But even after that I get the same syntax error.

Comment: Using `from __future__ import print_function` isn't likely to solve the problem unless you add it at the top of `image.py`. But even then, there will be Python 3 code in many of the other files and further syntax differences. You're best bet really is to install and use Python 3 if that's what the code is written in.

Comment: Ok, I just read where you got that file, have you downloaded all the resourses from that page? You have to put that import in top of the `image.py` file, but if there might be more incompatibilities.... just use version 3 of Python.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the code is designed for Python 3 and uses Python's `print` function. Anaconda provides Python 3, so try using that instead -- I can import image fine that way.

The precise location of the SyntaxError when I use Python 2 is here:

```
  File "image.py", line 98
    print("Hit Enter once the image is displayed.... ", end="")
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

which happens because Python2 is trying to print a tuple of values but the second element it gets for the tuple is an assignment.

[The docs](https://github.com/jimcarson/Coursera/blob/master/CodingTheMatrix/PythonTips.pdf) for your Coursera course tip you off about this (although it doesn't seem obvious) and warn you to use Python 3 and not Python 2.